# Use of SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE ahead of xmlRootElement

Tags: serialization, jackson, jaxb

I just want to understand what is the use of SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE. 
I have actually tried disabling the SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE and for the class I have annotated with xmlRootElement. Here in this case after disabling the SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE still after serializing I am getting the root value. To just avoid the root value I have to use the xmlType. 
So trying to understand then what is the use of SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE?

Sample code which I have tried

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
Public class Person {
@XmlElement(name = "insert")
    private int insert;

    @XmlElement(name = "update")
    private int update;
}
```

The above is the POJO class which I was trying to serialize and also I have used

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

So with the above code the output is

```
"person" {
       "insert" : 1,
       "update" : 0
}
```

In the same case if I try to change the xmlRootElement to XmlType in Person class the output is

```
{
  "insert" : 1,
  "update" : 0
}
```

So I am confused like what is the use of SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE if it is not giving the expected output?
I am using the Jackson version of 2.9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more into this found that with the help of CXF I was able to solve this by adding small config in applicationcontext.xml file

```
 <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
    <property name="dropRootElement" value="true" />
 </bean>
```